# An object is being set to NULL during an iteration- C++/MFC/ATL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, c++98

I have an object which holds a list of `CMapStringToString`. We traverse through the list in a `for` loop and within the loop, we traverse through the `CMapStringToString`.

Consider a Class Dataset which has a variable `currMap` of type `CMapStringToString` and it holds the current Map which is being processed.

Consider the following code snippet

```
DataSet->MoveFirst(); //currMap is pointing to first map in List
for(int i = 0; i ; i < Dataset->Map.size(); i++)
{
     CString s1 = Dataset->GetElemVal(key1); //Internally does a LookUp() on currMap variable with specified key
     CString s2 = Dataset->GetElemVal(key2);
     CString s3 = Dataset->GetElemVal(key3);
     CString s4 = Dataset->GetElemVal(key4);

DataSet->MoveNext(); //currMap Points to the next Map in the list
}

//Snippet for MoveNext
currMap = (CMapStringToString*) list->GetNext(pos);
CString str = currMap->LookUp(key1); //Str hold a valid value for the key

//Snippet for GetElemVal
if(currMap)
   str = currMap->LookUp(key1);
else
  //Print a log message if NULL and it prints as well after a few iterations
```

This works all fine for a 10-15 iterations out of 50-60 iterations. The `MoveNext()` points to a valid `currMap`, but when the Code reaches `GetElemVal`, internally `currMap` is suddenly `NULL` (0x000000).

I have printed one of the entries of the Map within the `MoveNext` method and it logged a correct value in the log file. But why would the same `currMap` be `NULL` by the time it reaches `GetElemVal`?

Please give me any pointers which would help me atleast reach any kind of solution. Thanks

Comment: Share more details about "Class Dataset which has a variable currMap " especially how the currMap is used ...

Comment: I have added some code. Hope this helps

Comment: `currMap = (CMapStringToString*) list->GetNext(pos);` looks scary ... did you check its return value?

Comment: Yes, Immediately after that line of code, I LookUp a key from the currMap and print it. It gives me a valid string.

Comment: If you change a container, all iterators to this container will be invalid. You should check, if the container, `currMap` points to, can be modified by your code.

Comment: If this happens consistently, consider setting/using a data breakpoint while debugging to determine where/how the currMap is being set to NULL.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/data-breakpoints-15-8-update/